# can't connect to mariadb as a non-root user remotely using dbeaver but I can connect to the server via ssh and access mariadb with no password

Tags: mariadb, dbeaver

I have been given access to a mariadb database and I have an issue accessing the db remotely.

I can connect to the server via ssh, and I was asked to enter mysql to login (no password required)

I'm trying dbeaver, I was able to connect to the server via ssh option, but I can't connect to the server with no password,

any options?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like I needed a password to connect remotely (no pass apparently was not a usuable option)

I stumbled uppon the following command:

`$ mysqlcheck --print-defaults`

this printed what appeared to be the default password setup for my user

`--socket=/tmp/mysql.sock --user=<mysqluser> --password=<mysqluserpass>`

and voila! I was able to connect using dbeaver :)

source: [mysqlcheck](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqlcheck/)